# Building framework with prior version of swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am developing a swift framework (in xcode 6 - swift 1.2) and recently updated to xcode 7

Xcode 7 introduce swift 2.0 and when trying to use my framework on apps being developed on xcode 7  i get errors on using prior version of xcode

I need to maintain the framework also for the use of developers using xcode 6

Is there a way to build a framework on xcode 7 as if it is build in xcode 6?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to build framework on Xcode 7 as if it was Xcode 6. Either continue your development using Xcode 6, or upgrade to 7 and release a new version of your framework that requires 7.